# Difference between git add -A and git add

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket, git-bash

Both commands are used to add all the changed files,
But is there any difference between these two

```
git add -A
```

and

```
git add .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

git add -A Adds all new, changed and deleted files to the staging area

git add . Adds new and changed files to the staging area but not deleted files

git add -u Adds all changed and deleted files to the staging area but will not add new files

Hope this helps :)